# how to use didChangeActiveBuilding on google maps ios sdk?

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7

I'm developing an app that uses the latest Google Maps iOS SDK.

My problem is that I can't get to call any of the methods `didChangeActiveBuilding` or `didChangeActiveLevel`.

I've included the delegate:
`@interface PCViewController () <GMSMapViewDelegate, GMSIndoorDisplayDelegate>`

I'm using also other events capture methods (`idleAtCameraPosition`, `didTapMarker`) and they are working fine.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you put in a chunk of code so I can verify?

Answer (score 0):

u can add following lines

```
 self.mapView.delegate=self;
 self.mapView.IndoorDisplay.delegate=self;
```

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
           {
           [super viewDidLoad];
             GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:28.566                                longitude:77.323976099999                                                            zoom:18];
    self.mapView=[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds  camera:camera];self.mapView.delegate=self;
    self.mapView.indoorDisplay.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];  
}
- (void) didChangeActiveLevel:(GMSIndoorLevel *) level
{NSLog(@"e:%@",level);} //function working fine when i add two line code

Comment: You should put the explanation in your answer.

Comment: ur question is that "Can anyone tell me what am I missing?"   i write the missing code which work for me as well as i thinks its work also for u.

Comment: Here's the deal: This post showed up in the low quality queue. If you don't edit it, it could be deleted. If you put some work into your answer, then it could survive and you could get more points.

Comment: thanks for suggestion  i am new.. in future i'll write expiation. And i thinks that u have experience to understand then i write two line which i miss in my code after adding two lines its working fine. so i write this answer